# How to auto scroll to input field when using a RecyclerView

Tags: android

When the keyboard appears the RecyclerView doesn't automatically scroll to the position of the selected input field. So the keyboard gets over the selected field.

I tried to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` to the activity as suggested in other questions but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Which layout manager are you using? There is a bug fix about this, but should work in most cases. The bugfix will be released in the next one or after :/, meanwhile, it might work to call `scrollToPosition(clickedItemPosition)` when keyboard comes up. (TextView focus)

Comment: I am using the LinearLayoutManager. I tried the scrollToPosition method, but it changes nothing. I think the item is already on the screen, so it doesn't need to scroll.

Comment: Are you talking about the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72117&q=RecyclerView&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars ? I don't see if it is related to my issue.

Comment: Nope, it was an internal bug, not sure if it was reported publicly. 
Basically, when you click on a text view, sometimes, it was not keeping the text view visible (after keyboard comes up).

Comment: The EditText gains focus before the keyboard is up